# How to prove this limit exist?

Tags: limits

How to prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=\frac{|x|^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4}$ for all $\alpha>0$?

I think in order to prove this limit exists, I should the value is all the same from different direction. How to prove at here?

Comment: $f=|x|^{\alpha} - \dfrac{|x|^{2+\alpha}}{x^2+y^4}$ consider limits for both. $|\dfrac{|x|^{2+\alpha}}{x^2+y^4}|\le \dfrac{|x|^{2+\alpha}}{x^2}$

Comment: Note $y^4/(x^2+y^4)<1$

Answer (score 1):

As Maesumi commented, we can observe that
$$
\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4} \le \frac{y^4}{y^4}=1.
$$
for $y\ne 0$ and if $y=0$, $\frac{y^4}{x^2+y^4} =0\le 1$. Then
$$
\left|\frac{|x|^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4}\right|\le |x|^\alpha.
$$
We can easily(?) show that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} |x|^\alpha = 0.
$$
By squeeze theorem, we are done.